# real analysis, functions, continuity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

[image]

Is the above function $f_2 : (\mathbb{R^2}, ||\cdot||_2) \to (\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)  $ continuous?

A similar question to one that I put up, I tried attempting $(x,y)=(1/n,1/n)$ but that just gives me zero.

Comment: Note that $$\forall x,y\in \mathbb R\left(x^2-y^2=|x|^2-|y^2|=(|x|-|y|)(|x|+|y|)\right).$$

Comment: Hint: $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$.

Comment: @GitGud therefore can I conclude it is continuous because it equals $(|x|-|y|)$ and that is a continuous function?

Comment: No, consider for instance $x\mapsto \begin{cases}x, &\text{if }x\neq  0\\ 2, &\text{if } x=0\end{cases}$ Would you conclude that this function is continuous just from $x\mapsto x$ being continuous?

Comment: oh okay that makes sense because it is not continuous at $x=0$ 

so in our example we have $$f_2(x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases}|x|-|y|, &\text{if }x^2+y^2\neq  0\\ 0, &\text{if } x^2+y^2=0\end{cases}$$ 

or would our conditions change?

Comment: What you wrote is correct. Now check whether the function is continuous or not. Where are you sure the function is continuous? Where do you suspect it might not be continuous?

Comment: I would assume it is continuous? ... because the function will equal zero when $x=y$ or if we considered the complex plane and $y=ix$ but we're only considering the real plane so we can ignore that

Comment: @smith If you want me to try to guide you to the answer, please answer my questions.

Comment: the reason I didn't answer your question is because I would essentially be guessing... it seems to be continuous at zero so my guess would be its not continuous at $|x|-|y|$ ... would it be because if $x^2+y^2 \neq 0$ $|x| - |y| = 0$ when $|x|=|y|$

Comment: @smith That's helpful feedback. You're misunderstanding my question. For instance in the one-variable function $x\mapsto \begin{cases}x, &\text{if }x\neq  0\\ 2, &\text{if } x=0\end{cases}$ is not continuous at $0$. It's not that "it's not continuous at $x$". Continuity is not evaluated at expressions, it is evaluated at points. Back to the given problem, saying the function is not continuous at $|x|-|y|$ doesn't really mean anything. Let me put it another way. Is $f_2$ continuous at $(1,1)$? How would you go about answering this?

Comment: everything seems easier in one variable, if we had $f_2(1,1)$ we get that the function is $0 \neq 1$ therefore it isn't continuous at the point $(1,1)$??

Comment: @smith Nope, not right. A two variable function $g$ is continuous at a given point $(a,b)$ of its domain, if, and only if, $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (a,b)}\left(g(x,y)\right)=g(a,b)$. It's similar in one variable. Now what is $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (1,1)}\left(f_2(x,y)\right)$? And what is $f_2(1,1)$? What can you conclude about continuity at $(1,1)$?

Comment: ohhh of course! I completely forgot the definition, thank you! .. so we have it is continuous at $(1,1)$ as 

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (1,1)}\left(f_2(x,y)\right)=f_2(1,1) =0 $$

Comment: so I need to find a point where this isn't satisfied and therefore the function is not continuous

Comment: @smith That's a plan. And what points you think are good candidates for this?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea, in the last 15 mins, I've attempted everything. it cant be a number as far as im aware? so am I looking at letting $x$ equal a function of $y$?

Comment: @smith How would you check continuity at $1$ of $x\mapsto \begin{cases}e^{x-1}-1, &\text{if }x\neq  1\\ 0, &\text{if } x=1\end{cases}$?

Comment: show that when limit of $x$ goes to $1$ we get zero, as define in the function

Comment: Good. Do the same for $f_2$.

Comment: but in one variable i'll be taking the limit as $x$ goes to $1$, in two variable how would I take the limit $(x,y)$ goes to $(x^2+y^2)$ unless I rearrange to find $x$ and $y$ separately but then I'd be going into the complex space

Comment: @smith The relevant thing is the point where the domain of the function "breaks off". You want to look at $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(|x|-|y|\right)$.

Comment: surely $$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(f_2(x,y)\right)=0 = f_2(0,0)$$

so that shows continuity at the point $(0,0)$

Comment: @smith Correct. The hardest part of the problem really was what I solved in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer attempt and also I've studied this topic recently myself for the first time but here it goes:
$
\lim_{(x,y)->(o,o)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{|x|+|y|}=0
$

because 
$
\frac{x^2-y^2}{|x|+|y|} \le \frac{||(x,y)||^2-||(x,y)||^2}{||(x,y)||+||(x,y)||} \le \frac{||(x,y)||^2+||(x,y)||^2}{||(x,y)||+||(x,y)||}=||(x,y)||=||(x,y)-(0,0)||
$

It's called Lipschitz-approximation in my country. I don't know if it's the same here. I'm open for feedback.

So at (0,0) the function is continuous and of course everywhere else too.

Comment: Re: Terminology, Lamguages:In English, a function $f :X\to Y$ is called Lipschitz -continuous iff $\exists K>0\;\forall p,q\in X\;(\|f(p)-f(q)\| _Y    \leq K\|p-q\|_X.$  In this case $Y=\mathcal R$ and $\|y\|=|y|.$  Your answer is fine. We can also observe$ |x^2-y^2|\leq$ $  x^2+y^2\leq$ $ x^2+ 2 |x|\cdot |y|+|y|^2=$ $(|x|+|y|)^2$. So $ |f_2(x,y)|\leq  |x|+|y|.$